# Javascript sorting, issue with filtering by integer

Tags: javascript

My script should be removing everything that doesn't match the value of the selected term from the drop-down list. However, it doesn't seem to be filtering at all. I'm using the exact same code for 2 other drop downs and only the term is causing issues. You can see the term is clearly present for each program on the demo page.

https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/whoward-dev-area/open-class-list-dev.php

```js
function detectChange5(termlist) {
   var select5 = document.getElementById('termlist');
   var keyword5 = select5.options[select5.selectedIndex].value;
   var clubDivs5 = document.getElementsByClassName('filtergroup');
   for (var f = 0; f<clubDivs5.length;f++) {
      if (clubDivs5[f].innerHTML.trim().indexOf(keyword5) === -1) {
         clubDivs5[f].style.display = "none";
      } 
      else {
            clubDivs5[f].style.display = "table-row";
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<select id="termlist" onchange="detectChange5(this)">
<option value="None">Term</option>
}
<option value="202265">Spring</option>
<option value="202295">Summer</option>
<option value="202335">Fall</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, you have no `.filtergroup` elements, so iterating through them isn't going to do anything...

Comment: You're comparing the keyword to the innerHTML of the whole row.  Some of the columns contain links, and their hrefs contain other term IDs.  So those rows are included in the results even though their term is not what you selected.  Maybe you should only compare the keyword to the text in the "term" column.

Comment: James Nailed it. The darn URLs had static term numbers. Changing it to dynamic variables solved the issues and the term now matches the links. Thanks for pointing out my error.